# Unable to run Angular 12 project

Tags: npm, nvm, angular12

I am using NVM to shift node versions as required. Used below command to use 14.15.0 version of `Node` as I want to run `Angular 12` project.
`nvm use 14.15.0`

I got the below output:
`F:\path\AngularProjectName>ng serve`

Then, the below output got printed.

> Node.js version v14.15.0 detected.
> The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.13.

> Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.

Hence, I have tried to use Node v20.9.0

Now, when I try to use the `ng serve` command, I am getting below error.
`F:\Path\AngularProjectName>ng serve`

> Workspace extension with invalid name (defaultProject) found.
> This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^17.0.0-next || >=17.0.0 <18.0.0,
> but Angular version 12.2.17 was found instead.

> Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.
> https://update.angular.io/

Can someone please suggest me how I can run Angular 12 project?

Comment: instead of `ng serve` try `npm run ng serve` when you run `ng serve` it's picking the global version of angualr cli installed, but your project needs a different version.

Comment: @Manish: I got below text after executing `npm run ng serve` command. →
Node.js  version v14.15.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.13.

Comment: which version of angular cli does your project uses? And may be try `npm install` in your project once..

Comment: @Manish: I'm using Angular12. I have already tried with npm install the same error as mentioned above.